# Android: menu option ShareAction versions

Tags: android, android-intent, share, android-optionsmenu

It is compiled without errors but I get this at runtime after the activity crashed:

```
 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is not supported, use MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider()
        at android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getActionProvider(MenuItemImpl.java:645)
        at com.......Activity.onCreateOptionsMenu
```

The line of code is in onCreateOptionsMenu()

```
shareProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
```

It said to use MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider() but it's in another import and I have minSdkVersion 15, targetSdkVersion 21

this is the activity

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Activity extends ActionBarActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener 
 {
    private ShareActionProvider shareProvider;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
        shareProvider = (ShareActionProvider) item.getActionProvider();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
                          .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "text");
        setShareIntent(shareIntent);
        return true;
    }

    private void setShareIntent(Intent shareIntent) {
        if (shareProvider != null) 
             shareProvider.setShareIntent(shareIntent);
    }
}
```

menu

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:context="com.......Activity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:title="Share" app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share"
    android:actionProviderClass="android.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `ActionBarActivity`, you must use [android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ShareActionProvider.html) instead of `android.widget.ShareActionProvider`:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:title="Share" app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider" />
```

And then use `MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider()` as the error message implies.

Note that the `ShareActionProvider` only becomes clickable after `setShareIntent()` is called - you should do that as soon as you can (either in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` or whenever the content you want to share is loaded/selected/ready rather than in `onOptionsItemSelected()`.

Comment: thank you. It's not crashing but still not working properly because the share button is not clickable. Is it right as I've done on menu creation and item selection?

Comment: Updated my answer to address when it becomes clickable - you need to call `setShareIntent` as soon as possible.

Comment: Also, the `ShareActionProvider` will only be clickable if there is a possible share target for your content. In your case, there will never be any share target, as you have not specified a MIME type in the `Intent`. Use `setType("text/plain")` to share plain text.

Comment: ok, so I prepare the intent in onCreateOptionsMenu and in onOptionsItemSelected I must only do startActivity(shareIntent)?
Is it common to have a strange red symbol with some white triangle next to the symbol of sharing? this is clickable but not the other one.

Comment: with MIME type now the sharing button works but what is the other one?

Comment: You don't do anything in `onOptionsItemSelected()` for a `ShareActionProvider` - it does everything for you. Per the [ShareActionProvider training](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionProvider), the icon that appears next to the share button is the last/highest ranking app to handle that intent. I suspect you are just seeing a left over symbol from when you didn't have the mime-type.

Comment: it was flipboard, I remembered about this symbol. Now it doesn't show it anymore, strange...

Comment: no, it is always there. I deleted the app and then reinstalled. Is it possible to hide it?

Comment: Can you remove the `android:icon` from your xml and see if that helps?

Comment: always there, it's the most used app